# How to access the form data (blob data) that is sent from XMLHttprequest and store it to specific location

Tags: php, post, xmlhttprequest, blob, form-data

I have convert a canvas element into blob data with the `canvas.toBlob()` function , into variable `blob` .
Then I append it to the `formdata`

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('my-file',blob,fileName);
```

I use XMLHttpRequest to send the `formData` to `storeImage.php`

```
var sendImage = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url ="https://192.168.x.x/storeImage.php";
sendImage.open("POST",url, true);
sendImage.send(formData);
```

Inside `storeImage.php` I have these lines of code to at least try to access the formData first

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST['my-file'])
?>
```

So that I can store it as file later on .

But result from `var_dump` is as followed .

```
Warning: Undefined array key "my-file" in E:\xampp\htdocs\wasp_bee\storeImage.php on line 2
NULL
```

How can I at least access the posted formData in the php file , so I can finally proceed to save the blob data as file to the server (./img) using the `file_put_contents` function ?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Using json bodies this helped me under linux: `file_get_contents('php://input')`, I don't know if that also works with windows..

Comment: I have try to use `if(!file_get_contents('php://input')){ echo "can't read it " ;}`
It prints out can't read it . Seems like no file was sent ... It could be the issue between the php and javascript connection then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binary files are accessible by using the `$_FILES` array.

> An associative array of items uploaded to the current script via the
> HTTP POST method. The structure of this array is outlined in the POST
> method uploads section.

The uploaded file can store at your address by using the `move_uploaded_file` function.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['my-file']['tmp_name'], 'address to store file');
```

Checking file error, name, format, etc are very important please check them at the main reference.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: I have tried using this line of code in php to print it out `echo "Filename: " . $_FILES['my-file']['name']."<br>";`

But error like this `Warning: Undefined array key "my-file" in E:\xampp\htdocs\wasp_bee\storeImage.php on line 2

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in E:\xampp\htdocs\wasp_bee\storeImage.php on line 2
Filename: ` 
shows up . I open the php file manually after posting the form , does that have to do with the error ?

Comment: Please use `var_dump($_GET, $_POST, $_FILES)` and send results.

Comment: array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } , nothing , seems like the php file is not receiving the data sent from XMLHttpRequest , not at all ...

Comment: Maybe data will send as a string, so after `open` add this line in your JavaScript: `sendImage.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');`

Comment: After adding this line , the result is still the same ... 
I also try to print the XMLHttpRequest response 
It print out something like this ... 
`array(0) { } array(968) { ["------WebKitFormBoundaryqJZbppGiaE4mKvk9 Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name"]=> string(258) ""my-file"; filename="my-file" Content-Type: image/png �PNG  IHDR^^� wx��n�;�*_���W�>�_?��?dw��a��~#��N6���7;�l7��le���F����lw ��r�����t�J 
  ... `

Comment: If I didn't add the line , the result is like this `array(0) { } array(0) { } array(1) { ["my-file"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(7) "my-file" ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["tmp_name"]=> string(24) "E:\xampp\tmp\php7644.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(231247) } }`

Comment: From this line of code `sendImage.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if (sendImage.readyState==4 && sendImage.status==200){
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=sendImage.responseText;
                }
            }`

Comment: Both of them are ok. I suggest don't add that header and use `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['my-file']['tmp_name'], 'address to store file');`.

Comment: for example: `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['my-file']['tmp_name'], __DIR__ . '/a.png');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243777/discussion-between-amirreza-noori-and-akizukilenn).

Comment: Yes , the `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['my-file']['tmp_name'], 'address to store file');` works . 
Even the php var_dump array is zero , It works . Took  me 2 days to realise you can just do that . 
Best solution selected .